# Tailwind CSS, React, Next.JS: Anyone know why bg-cover is not working correctly on my mobile device?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Works perfectly in all screen sizes on my desktop, but on my iPhone, the background stretches to the bottom of the content, and not the screen height as it should. The bg-cover property is found in the div right below the Head tags.

````
        <Head>
          <title>Justin Waves</title>
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <div className="pb-[300px] md:pb-[350px] relative min-h-screen bg-main-bg bg-cover bg-fixed bg-center">
          <MenuButton />
          <Header />
          <MainImage
            releaseName={release.releaseName}
            releaseType={release.releaseType}
            releaseUrl={release.releaseUrl}
            isDebut={release.isDebut}
          />
          <StreamEmbed />
          <h1 className="font-thin text-white text-center text-5xl py-4 pt-20 pb-20 ">
            PURCHASE RELEASES
          </h1>
          <p className="text-sm text-left text-[#A34141] animate-pulse px-5">
            Latest Release ⤵
          </p>
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:gird-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-3 md:gap-6 p-2 md:p-6   ">
            {sortedPosts.map((post) => (
              <Link key={post._id} href={`/post/${post.slug.current}`}>
                <div
                  className="border rounded-lg group cursor-pointer overflow-hidden relative  bg-filter bg-white backdrop-blur-xl bg-opacity-30 text-white"
                  data-cy="article"
                >
                  <img
                    className="h-60 w-full object-cover group-hover:scale-110 transition-transform duration-200 ease-in-out "
                    src={urlFor(post.mainImage).url()!}
                    alt=""
                  />
                  <div className="flex justify-between p-5 ">
                    <div>
                      <p className="text-lg font-bold ">{post.title}</p>
                      <p className="text-xs">{post.description}</p>
                    </div>
                    <img
                      className="h-12 w-12 rounded-full"
                      src={urlFor(post.author.image).url()!}
                      alt=""
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
          <img src="/secret.png" alt="" className=" w-72 mx-auto" />
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>```
````